# Three-fiber canvas size

Tags: reactjs, canvas, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

I have a question regarding the three-fiber canvas size. I need a fixed canvas width and height. Unfortunately I have not found out how to change the canvas width and height. Even though I can change the sizes with `style={{width:` 100px`, height:` 100px`}}`, it is not the right thing. The canvas should be bigger than the div. does anyone have an idea how to do this with three-fiber?

```
<Canvas
    size={[`2000px`,`3000px`]}
    style={{width: `100%`, height: `auto`, position: `relative` }}
    ref={canvas}
    shadows
    camera={{position: [10, 0, 80], fov: 45}}
>
    <Suspense fallback={false}>
        <Content/>
    </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 22):

React Three Fiber's canvas will take the width and height of the parent container.

Instead of setting the width and height on the `Canvas` component, try setting the width and height on the parent instead, like this:

```
<div style={{ width: "50vw", height: "50vh" }}>
  <Canvas flat linear>
    <App />
  </Canvas>
</div>
```

[**View Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-elbakyan-ewytp?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 3):

Canvas in three-fiber takes on the width of its parent container. just resize whatever div it is being contained by.